# Generate URL in controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action in my controller that renders JSON back to the client:

```
@data = [{label:"foo", url:"..."}, ...]

render :json => @data
```

Basically "data" is an array of objects that each have a label and url property. The want to generate the URL on the server-side instead of handing this data to the client and having it iterate over it to generate the URL strings.

If I could use the "link_to" method it would look like this:

link_to "foo", {:action => 'some_action', :foobar => {}}

Basically link to the /foobar/some_action

What's the best way to generate the URL while in the controller since I don't have the handy "link_to" method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the method [**ActionController::Base#url_for**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for)

For Rails 3 see [ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor#url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor/url_for)

Comment: I chose this as the answer b/c it will also let me specify the protocol (http, https) which I need. However, I didn't test whether the link_to would pick the correct protocol based on the HTTP request that came in. Thanks for both answers.

Comment: Thanks. Note that I suggested url_for because I think you only need a URL, not the link tag that returns link_to. In fact, link_to uses url_for to generate the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the view helper methods in your controller just like any other module, and those methods will be available:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def ajax_method
    link_to "foo", {:action => 'some_action', :foobar => {}}
  end
end
```